# How is Entity Framework Core with Dependency Injection disposed?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core you would normally use something like this, which should work in pretty much all cases:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
    await dbContext.Entities.WhereAsync(e => e.Something == somethingElse);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

You can also use Dependency Injection with the database context. Now you would add the database context to the DI container and inject this into the classes/controllers/constructors/methods where you need it:

```
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, collection) => {
        string connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
        collection.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();

...

public class Foo {
    public Foo(MyDbContext dbContext) { }
}
```

However, injecting this into a class/constructor you would usually keep the instance as a local variable, which is fair enough, but there's no longer any possibility to use the `using` statements. Now two different methods could end up using the same dbContext at the same time which will most likely cause concurrency issues.

If the dbContext was not injected but just used in a `using` statement then there should be no problem with concurrency and the object would be disposed at the end of each method.

So how would you correctly handle concurrency and disposing with Entity Framework Core and Dependency Injection?

Comment: what is the problem with concurrency  when you AddTransient or AddScoped to DI?

Answer (score 0):

By default the extension methods `AddDbContext` do:

```
services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>()
```

So in case of `AddDbContext`, a new instance will be created for each request and would get disposed once the work is done (objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests). So, you shouldn't have any problem with concurrency  here.

Also you can add context to DI as transient if you need a new instance for every controller and every service.

Comment: So you should basically not use constructor injection with a dbcontext then, because then the same instance can be called from different places simultaneously? Which means that DI for database contexts is mostly usable for specific methods, not for classes?

Comment: no, definitely no. it is recommended to use dbcontext in constructors and resolve it as scoped. See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I can't see any recommendations in that link that says you should use constructor injection for EF.

Comment: You should use whatevent you want. if you don't want to care about context lifetime then let do it by DI and use constructors. If you want to control lifetime of context then create instance manually in using block. Creating and disposing of many (every time when method run) objects may impact the performance.